# storing multiple value in KeychainItemWrapper

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using KeychainItemWrapper to store login information, I have used kSecAttrAccount and kSecValueData to store emails and passwords. Apart from this two I want to store some more bool values to decided some specification. How can I do this, do we have another constant like  this or we have to use same constants to store multiple value. If so how do we differentiate those values...

Hope my question is understandable..

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kSecAttrLabel also..

Comment: all sample codes are storing only username and password in Keychain, So Is it a goo approach to store other than those two?

Comment: that's not a problem at all..if you need value like a same reuse object throughout the application,don't hesitate to use like this.. otherwise you don't have a problem to use the value like a new object better go by NSUserdefault or core data